# Hide files.excluded from explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is supposed to work I think, but correct me if I'm wrong. I have this list of files in my files.exlucde:

```
{
    "files.exclude":
    {
        "**/.DS_Store":true,
        "**/.git":true,
        "**/.gitignore":true,
        "**/.gitmodules":true,
        "**/*.booproj":true,
        "**/*.pidb":true,
        "**/*.suo":true,
        "**/*.user":true,
        "**/*.userprefs":true,
        "**/*.unityproj":true,
        "**/*.dll":true,
        "**/*.exe":true,
        "**/*.pdf":true,
        "**/*.mid":true,
        "**/*.midi":true,
        "**/*.wav":true,
        "**/*.gif":true,
        "**/*.ico":true,
        "**/*.jpg":true,
        "**/*.jpeg":true,
        "**/*.png":true,
        "**/*.psd":true,
        "**/*.tga":true,
        "**/*.tif":true,
        "**/*.tiff":true,
        "**/*.3ds":true,
        "**/*.3DS":true,
        "**/*.fbx":true,
        "**/*.FBX":true,
        "**/*.lxo":true,
        "**/*.LXO":true,
        "**/*.ma":true,
        "**/*.MA":true,
        "**/*.obj":true,
        "**/*.OBJ":true,
        "**/*.asset":true,
        "**/*.cubemap":true,
        "**/*.flare":true,
        "**/*.mat":true,
        "**/*.meta":true,
        "**/*.prefab":true,
        "**/*.unity":true,
        "build/":true,
        "Build/":true,
        "Library/":true,
        "library/":true,
        "obj/":true,
        "Obj/":true,
        "ProjectSettings/":true,
        "temp/":true,
        "Temp/":true
    }
}
```

This is supposed to hide them from the Explorer right? For me they are only grayed out. Is this a bug or intended? I do not know whether to report a bug or is this something that is intended.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem/question is whether the files/folders specified in the "files.exclude" file should hide them from the explorer tab in visual studio code.